# не могу загрузить в базу данных mysql значения golang

Tags: mysql, база-данных, golang

```go
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

func main() {

    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "mysql:mysql@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/golang")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    insert, err := db.Query("INSERT INTO 'users' ('name', 'age') VALUES('alex', 43)")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer insert.Close()

    fmt.Println("ok")
}
```

код выдает такую ошибку 
[image: ошибка]

но если задокументировать
эту часть кода 
[image: код]
то все работает нормально,
в чем проблема ?
бд выглядит так
[image: бд]

Comment: А вы проверяли параметры подключения ? Возможно не тот порт, не открыт на рабочей машине порт, не настроен проброс(в случае работы через роутер). И одинарные кавычки здесь `('name', 'age')` я вообще никогда не использую) и здесь `'users'` тоже

Comment: Вы меняли порт в настройках sql? Ибо порт по умолчанию если верить Гуглу, 1433. А у вас 3306

Comment: @umd, так это локальная бд. и порт там 3306

Comment: @umd, убрал кавычки, нечего не поменялось

Comment: вы пробовали менять порт и открывает порт? Вы напрямую подключены или через роутер?

Comment: @umd напрямую, порт пробовал менять

Comment: Порт открыт на компе у вас?

Comment: `db.Ping()` работает?